# How to select all elements under a class?

Tags: css

I currently have this in my css file.

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and I have another class called

```
.chat{
...
}
```

but I dont want to use that previous `*` selector. I only want to select all the elements that come under `.chat` class. Not all the elements in the whole damn website, but all the elements that comes under the `.chat` class. How do I do it?

Comment: is `.chat::before` what you're looking for?

Comment: please elaborate your need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [**universal selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) preceded by a white-space combinator after your `.chat` class like so:

```
.chat * { ... }
```

What this is doing is: **Match all elements that are descendants of `.chat`.**